# How to execute SQL command with parameters in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to make a bash script which will add user to my custom table in MySQL database. I have username as script argument stored in variable $USERNAME and I need to execute this query into MySQL server:

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('$USERNAME', password)
```

I know how to execute a sql file but that won't help me when I have username in variable. The only way I can think of is to execute php file with GET values and execute sql command in php. And I'm not eve sure that with php will work as I think.

Is there any better way?

Thanks

EDIT:
After your helpfull answers I went with this command which works:

```
mysql -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 -e "INSERT INTO table VALUES (\"$USERNAME@\",\"password\")" database
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `mysql -e "command"`? In your case, `mysql -e "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$USERNAME', password)`

Comment: I wasn't familiar with mysql command but now I am. Thanks for tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command would be:

```
mysql -pyourpasswordwithoutspaces -e "Your insert query goes here with semicolon;"
```

I'm not sure if the semicolons are necessary or not, but it always good to provide them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="example"

mysql <<MYSQL
INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$USERNAME', password);
MYSQL
```

Comment: I didn't know about heredoc before. I looked it up and it seems good but I'll use it on some more difficult queries.