# execute .sql file in bash with params

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash, shell

I want to execute a .sql file in a bash file but I need to pass parameters to the .sql from the bash file. I think it's a simple solution but I can't figure it out.

This is what I have so far:

**.SQL File**

```
SET @columnValue = &1;
UPDATE tblTest SET Description = @columnValue;
```

**Bash File**

```
#!/bin/bash
columnValue=$1
mysql -uroot -ppassword testDB < SQLscript.sql $columnValue
```

**Shell**

```
sh myBashFile.sh "testColumnValue"
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you tell us what is currently happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of setting SQL parameters first and then loading your .sql file.

In your bash script you can use `mysql` with the `-e` option to execute an SQL statement. The same method must then be used to tell mysql to load the file instead of reading it using bash.

See [this example script](http://www.gensale.net/537/).

If you only want to execute a single statement, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459505/how-to-execute-sql-command-with-parameters-in-bash-script).

Comment: Your solution is working fine thank you!! :) So if i understand it correctly there is no way to pass params to a .sql file without setting mysql variable ?

Comment: You could generate a bash script that replaces the variable tokens in your .sql file before handing it to `mysql`. However, I guess that would unnecessarily complicate things.